How do I implement the UI as in the image below using constraint layout with XML in android studio?
how do I implement the below UI using constraint layout with xml in android studio?


If you wish to draw the curves the use bezier curve with custom view. Otherwise you can use image in the background of just the pause button that looks like its part of the view behind but its not.

Please ask more precise question next time as to which part is the problem because you just stated a general question. also mention what have you tried and what is not working like you want etc.
